# Associate Route 53 AWS Domain with AWS EC2, including path

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I've bought a domain through AWS Route 53 (let's assume **domain.com**).

I have an AWS EC2 Ubuntu Instance with LAMP, and Elastic IP (let's assume `1.2.3.4`).

Now, I want to connect `domain.com` to `http://1.2.3.4/websitepath`. I made a Hosted Zone with **A RECORD** that points to `1.2.3.4` then a CNAME Record called "WWW" that points to `https://1.2.3.4/websitepath`.

The problem is that when I surf to `www.domain.com` it redirects me to `http://1.2.3.4/` instead of `http://1.2.3.4/websitepath`.

Any help?

Comment: I think the answer is no: https://serverfault.com/a/47176

Comment: You can't do that. R53 only resolves to IP address, not to an url path.

Answer (score 0):

The Domain Name Service (DNS) is a **telephone directory for IP addresses**.

DNS protocols **convert a domain name** (eg `app.example.com`) into an **IP address** (eg `1.2.3.4`).

Then, your computer establishes a connection with that IP address. Any other information sent in that connection request depends upon the protocol being used (eg SSH, HTTP, PING, RDP). Thus, the 'path' portion of your request is part of the HTTP protocol and has nothing to do with the DNS lookup of a domain name.

Therefore, **it is not possible to create a domain name that points to a specific path on a server**. This is how DNS is designed and is unrelated to Amazon Route 53 in particular.

Comment: So, in this case I've to create an Instance for every site? If I use a VPS for more websites, how can I set up all domains properly?

Comment: One webserver can accept requests sent to multiple domain names (search for information about a **virtual host**). When a request arrives at the webserver, it can examine the domain name that was used and either present a particular website or redirect the browser to an alternate URL. You are welcome to create a new Question with the specific details of what you are wanting to achieve.